# Real Analysis, Folland problem 2.48. why $\iint\!f\mathrm d\nu\mathrm d\mu=1\;?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\;X=Y=N$, $\;M=N=2^N$, $\;\mu=\nu=$ counting measure. Define $f(m,n)=1$ if $m=n$, $f(m,n)=−1$ if $m=n+1$, and $f(m,n)=0$ otherwise.
Then $\int|f|\,\mathrm d(\mu\times\nu)=\infty$, and $\,\iint f\,\mathrm d\mu\mathrm d\nu\;$ and $\;\iint f\mathrm d\nu\mathrm d\mu\;$ exist and are unequal.

I'm working on this problem and I'm trying to understand why $\;\iint f\mathrm d\nu\mathrm d\mu=1$.

I saw a couple of solutions but I don't get the logic there and they seem quite inconsistent in their reasoning.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please write the problem down.

Comment: @OPK You've written $M = N = 2N$, which doesn't make sense. Please correct this

Answer (score 3):

I assume that $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,\dots\}$. If your author defines $\Bbb N$ as starting from $1$, the same basic approach still works, but details must be changed appropriately.

To calculate $\iint f\, d\nu d\mu$, we can proceed as follows. First, write the iterated integral out in full as
\begin{align}
\iint f\, d\nu d\mu &= \int_{\Bbb N}\left(\int_\Bbb N  f(m,n)\,d\nu(n)\right)\,d\mu(m).
\end{align}
With this in mind, we must first compute the integral $\int_\Bbb N  f(m,n)\,d\nu(n)$, which should give us a function of $m$. Let $f_m(n) = f(m,n)$, and let $g(m) = \int f_m \,d\nu = \int_\Bbb N  f(m,n)\,d\nu(n)$. Note that $\iint f\,d\nu d\mu = \int g(m)\,d\mu(m)$.

For any given $m \in \Bbb N$, there are two possible values of $n$ for which $f(m,n) \neq 0$: when $n = m$, we have $f(m,n) = 1$, and when $n = m-1$ (so that $m = n+1$), we have $f(m,n) = -1$. For any $m \geq 1$, this means that
$$
f_m(n) = 
\begin{cases}
-1 & n=m-1\\
1 & n = m\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This definition does not apply when $m = 0$, since $m-1 = -1$ is not an element of $\Bbb N$. Instead, we simply have
$$
f_0(n) = \begin{cases}
1 & n=0\\
0 & n>0.
\end{cases}
$$
Now, you must use the definition of counting measure (and integration relative to this measure) to show that the following is true: for any $m \neq 0$, we have
$$
g(m) = \int f_m \, d \nu = 0.
$$
On the other hand, we find that
$$
g(0) = \int f_0\, d\nu = 1.
$$
That is,
$$
g(m) = \begin{cases}
1 & m = 0\\
0 & m > 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Conclude that $\iint f \,d\nu d\mu = \int g\,d\mu = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! you helped me a lot